# Mounting heavy shelves to brick wall

Tags: drill, brick, masonry

I've an [aluminium shelf that's 150cm wide](https://www.strackk.com/en/shelves/basic-black-ral9005), it came with 8 of [these 10x50 plastic plugs](https://www.fischer.co.uk/en-gb/products/standard-fixings/plastic-fixings/duopower/555110-duopower-10-x-50-s) and 6x60 universal screws.

I've drilled into my masonry wall with a 60mm deep with a masonry bit and installed the shelves. Once there's enough load on them (I'm guessing around 70kg, plus the 20kg for the shelf itself) they couldn't bear the load and started slanting downwards.

Someone suggested drilling with a 8mm bit and using the same 10x50mm plugs to have a tighter fit but I'm really looking forward to hearing other suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Drilling smaller holes will not work, you won't be able to get the plugs in. And if you can, then your wall must be light weight blockwork and you'll need a plug suitable for lightweight blocks (or a resin type fastener).

Did you tap the plug a little ways into the wall (15mm or so)? If not, then it's likely that the hold point wasn't deep enough into the actual masonry blocks of the wall but rather holding in the weak plasterwork.

These fasteners are absolutely top notch and should hold up huge loads. If not, then the substrate must be too soft or the plasterwork too thick (dot and dab drywall maybe).

[image: How to install plugs into a masonry wall]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I didn't tap the plugs in like you've suggested but this makes me think that the job can be done with longer screws.

Comment: It is all about the depth or thickness of the plaster. Any wall plug must be fully into the walling material to hold properly.